# Facebook Programming Challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm

Mastermind is a game of two players. In the beginning, first player decides a secret key, which is a sequence `(s1,s2,...sk)` where `0 < si <= n`, Then second player makes guesses in rounds, where each guess is of form `(g1,g2, ...gk)`, and after each guess first player calculates the score for the guess. Score for a guess is equal to number of i's for which we have `gi = si`.

For example if the secret key is `(4,2,5,3,1)` and the guess is `(1,2,3,7,1)`,then the score is 2, because
`g2 = s2` and `g5 = s5`.

Given a sequence of guesses, and scores for each guess, your program must decide if there exists at least one secret key that generates those exact scores.

Input

First line of input contains a single integer *C* `(1 <=C <= 100)`. C test-cases follow. First line of each test-case contains three integers *n*, *k* and *q*. `(1 <=n,k <=11, 1<=q<=8)`. Next *q* lines contain the guesses.

Each guess consists of *k* integers `gi,1, gi,2,....gi,k` separated by a single space, followed by the score for the guess *bi* `(1 <= gi,j <=n for all 1 <=i <=q, 1 <=j <=k; and 0 <= bi <=k )`

Output

For each test-case, output "Yes" (without quotes), if there exists at least a secret key which generates those exact scores, otherwise output "No".

Sample Input

```
2
4 4 2
2 1 2 2 0
2 2 1 1 1
4 4 2
1 2 3 4 4
4 3 2 1 1
```

Sample Output

```
Yes
No
```

I am not able to think anything else except brute force i.e. by generating all the possible keys and checking the respective score for all the guesses 
The complexity is a very high will do approx (11^11)*8 operations

Plz suggest something how to do this in time?

time limit: 3 sec

Comment: I think they're called "challenges" for a reason. Note how they're not called "ask-someone-else-to-do-it-for-you"s.

Comment: the challenge is already over

was asked in my college by facebook when it came for recruitment

Comment: The challenge is not one of time or being better some perceived competition. It's about being able to solve a problem, which is *always* a challenge until you master the craft.

Comment: there are a few pages in one of Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++ books about this problem. Takes about 100 lines of code IIRC.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Personally, I find this question interesting and would encourage people to post them on SO.

Comment: -1 Thanks for closing this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the [bulls and cows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows) game. There's a lot of information about it in the web, and on the wiki article you can find links to the implementations. It should be fairly easy to adapt them to your exact challenge.

Comment: I fear it differs quite a bit. In bulls and cows you get to choose the next guess, whereas in the OP's problem, guesses are given.

Comment: This is actually exactly MSP-BLACK - Mastermind Satisfiability Problem using only black pegs. It's proven to be NP-Complete.